# Should I TRUNCATE TABLE before I DROP TABLE to avoid logging overhead?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I understand that using `TRUNCATE` is a minimally logged operation and does not log the deletion of each record while `DROP` logs delete operations.

So, is it safe to assume that if I want to get rid of a relatively large table and I want this to happen as QUICKLY and with as LITTLE logging overhead as possible I should `TRUNCATE TABLE` before I `DROP TABLE`? Does doing this in `RECOVERY SIMPLE` make any difference?

I should note that this needs to happen in an automated fashion (within pre-written scripts) because this will be deployed to client databases where both downtime and log file growth could be a problem.

Comment: My memory is that the concern is moot if the recovery setting is `SIMPLE`.

Comment: So does that mean that DROP TABLE is considered minimally logged when using SIMPLE recovery model? I haven't seen any definitive answers on that.

Comment: You can roll back a DROP also, even in SIMPLE recovery, as long as you're still inside the same transaction. There aren't many truly "minimally logged" operations in SQL Server.

Comment: @Aaron - As a rule most of the "minimally logged" operations log page extents and metadata changes instead of row level changes though, correct?

Comment: Yes, that is how I understand it, but different people may have different interpretations.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

While TRUNCATE doesn't log individual rows, it does log for the page/extent. This is why you can rollback a truncate (which not a lot of people know). My guess is that if you just truncate then drop it will actually be slower than a drop on its own. If you commit in between, maybe not, but it would also depend on the log activity, recovery model, when you hit a checkpoint, etc.

Why is the speed important here? It's not like users are using the table if you're about to drop it...

Why don't you test it? Unless someone has run an extensive study about this covering several different variables, I doubt you're going to get much more than quasi-educated guesses.

Comment: The reason why speed is a factor is because this is part of an upgrade process to a production database and downtime will need be kept to a minimum. Honestly, log file growth is probably more of an issue.

Comment: Why not drop the table AFTER the upgrade process? It's not like it needs to be GONE before the upgrade finishes, it just needs to be replaced with a different version of the table (I assume). I would say transfer it to a different schema or rename it, then you can drop it later when users aren't waiting.

Comment: Aaron, you are correct about the table being replaced. It's part of a "large scale" data migration project. But the problem is that this has to be run in an automated fashion due to how our deployment model works. I don't really have the option of doing anything manually in this case.

Comment: @OMG - it's pretty awesome.  It just HAS to be enclosed in a transaction, but you can `ROLLBACK` a `TRUNCATE`.

Comment: @Justin you can automate what he's saying...`EXEC sp_rename TableName TableName_OLD; <do stuff>; DROP Tablename_OLD`

Comment: @Justin, what do you mean? If you're currently building automated deployment scripts that can either say DROP TABLE or TRUNCATE TABLE; DROP TABLE, why couldn't the same scripts issue a rename or schema transfer instead, and maybe create a one-time job that issues the drop later (or simply run the drop at the end of the script, when the database has been brought back online)?

Comment: @JNK, that's exactly what my plan was. My big question is whether or not I will minimize transaction logging by issuing a TRUNCATE first.

Comment: @Justin - I think unless we are talking about hundred-GB size tables you probably won't notice a difference.

Comment: @Aaron, yes the scripts can issue rename and will indeed be doing that as well. But because of our deployment model and how this is going to be run on client systems in a "packaged" nature, everything needs to happen at the time they execute this upgrade process. It will happen through an upgrade tool and we won't have the option of doing anything manually either before or after.

Comment: How does the upgrade tool automatically mark that an upgrade is complete?

Comment: @Aaron, successful completion of SQL scripts as well as other upgrade components - basically, no exceptions thrown. There is also an internal version number that is stamped at the end of the upgrade process that is proof that an upgrade has completed.

Comment: Well you're making it extremely difficult to find ways to save you time during the upgrade process if that's all there is to it. :-(

Comment: @Aaron I'm not sure if you feel that I'm withholding helpful info, but essentially yes that's all there is to it. But it does seem that after doing some testing the difference between the two options is negligible as @JNK suggested. Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 2):

In my experience truncate is way faster than drop, specially for large data sets.